# get percentage of common column between two row in SQL

Tags: sql, row

I have a table like this :

```
Pseudo |eyes   |hair   |gender
-------|-------|-------|-------
mat01  |brown  |black  |male
Alex   |blue   |black  |male
```

And i need to get the percentage of exactly same field for two given pseudo

in this case, for pseudos mat01 and alex, it should return 0.66 (2/3), because they have the same hair and gender, but not the same eyes.
Does anybody have an idea on how to do this? It should be in one SQL request if possible.

Thank you

Comment: How do you know which two it would compare in a table of hundreds?  Or should it compare every 2? or more than 2?

Comment: Which DBMS are you using?

Comment: I dont think you can do it in a query, you would need a extra column for each row, I would suggest you do it on the application.

Comment: Add more sample data, and give us the expected result.

Answer (score 2):

No need for case expressions or anything.. you can simply do that:

```
SELECT t.pseudo,s.pseudo,
       ((t.eyes = s.eyes) + (t.hair = s.hair) + (t.gender = s.gender))/3 as YourAvg
FROM YourTable t
INNER JOIN YourTable s
ON(t.pseudo <> s.pseudo)
```

Thats because a condition like t.eyes = s.eyes is a boolean, if its true then it returns 1 and if not it returns 0 .
This will give you each pseudo compared to each pseudo.. you can change it to show only the pseudo you want

Comment: change b.pseudo to s to match your table aliases

Comment: How do you know who are you comparing agasint in this solution?

Comment: xQbert thanks , @LuisTellez I don't, it compares everyone to everyone , he didn't specified which one he wants so I left it this way, and I mentioned it in the answer that he will have to filter the one he wants

Comment: missed one in the select :P

Comment: missed what? @xQbert

Comment: `SELECT t.pseudo,b.pseudo,` table alias b should be switched to s.  you corrected the inner join on clause but missed the one in the select.

Comment: :| I hate those typos.. so hard to see :P @xQbert

Comment: Yea you were.. I've been fast enough:)

Answer (score 0):

This is one method assuming you want to compare every pseudo to the others without duplication and self compare:

Like A-->B

but not like A--> A and not B--> A

```
SELECT A.Pseudo, B.Pseudo, (case when a.eyes = B.eyes then 1 else 0 end+
       case when a.hair = b.hair then 1 else 0 end+
       case when a.gender = b.gender then 1 else 0 end)/3 as mAvg
FROM table A
INNER JOIN table B 
 on A.Pseudo < B.Pseudo
```

Comment: How do you know who are you comparing agasint in this solution?

Comment: So lets say table has pseudo's of A, B, C, D, E.  A would compare against b, c,d,e.  B would compare against c,d,e, c would compare against D,e, d would compare against e and that's it.  Since I'm listing both pseduo's names in each row you can see each compairison

Answer (score 0):

If you need to know how everyone compare to everyone else you should do it in your application rather than in the DB, as you would need an extra column for each user to know the % and the ID of the user you are comparing to.